# Parse hw_clock output in Python

Tags: python, python-datetime

The output of

`/sbin/hwclock --show --utc`

looks like

`2017-06-01 16:04:47.029482+1:00`

How to parse this string into a datetime object in Python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the third party library `python-dateutil` (`pip install python-dateutil`):

```
>>> import dateutil.parser
>>> dateutil.parser.parse('2017-06-01 16:04:47.029482+1:00')
datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 1, 16, 4, 47, 29482, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 3600))
```

If you don't want to use a third party library:

```
import datetime
import re


def parse_iso_timestamp(clock_string):
    # Handle offset < 10
    clock_string = re.sub(r'\+(\d):', r'+0\1', clock_string)

    # Handle offset > 10
    clock_string = re.sub(r'\+(\d\d):', r'+\1', clock_string)

    # Parse
    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(clock_string, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z')

    return dt


print(parse_iso_timestamp('2017-06-01 16:04:47.029482+1:00').__repr__())
print(parse_iso_timestamp('2017-06-01 16:04:47.029482+10:00').__repr__())
```

Which outputs:

```
datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 1, 16, 4, 47, 29482, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(0, 3600)))
datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 1, 16, 4, 47, 29482, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(0, 36000)))
```

Comment: I am not afraid of dependencies. If a library make my life easier, I extend the install_requires list in setup.py :-) Thank you for this answer.

Answer (score 3):

using just datetime:

```
import datetime

s = "2017-06-01 16:04:47.029482+1:00"
try:
    stamp, zone = s.rsplit('+', 1)
    sign = '+'
except ValueError:
    stamp, zone = s.rsplit('-', 1)
    sign = '-'
zone = int(zone.replace(':', ''))
new_s = '%s%s%04d' % (stamp, sign, zone)

print(new_s)
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(new_s, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z")
print(dt.__repr__())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse a string into datetime object using [`datetime.strptime()`.](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) It takes the date string and format as input and return datetime object method.

Answer (score 0):

split by space fist value is date like 2017-06-01

d =date.split(" ")[0]

split by dot to get time
t = data.split(" ")[1].split(".")[0]